# SQL group by with ungrouped columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a log table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    oid        integer(10),
    department  integer(10),
    cid         integer(10),
    status      integer(1) comment 'statuses: 1-open, 2-accept, 3-done',
    recordtime  datetime
);
```

This table stores some data about status assignment. oid - organization, cid - card id.
Organizations belogns to departments, when organization update card(set new status) in this table inserts row

I try to select statistic data from that table, e.g.: select max/min accept time, max/min done time and average accept/done time by department or by organization (oid).

[here is sql fiddle of the example table and my query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/94015/8).

The problem is how to get cid in selected columns when group by department, oid and oid and cid when group by department. In other words: i want to know organization (oid) and card id (cid) with, for instance, max accept time when i select grouped rows

I need these columns for several joins

**UPD:**
Thanks to **Roman Pekar**, his answer led me to the right path. I use his second query to write my final queries.

First: select average accept/done time, max/min accept/done time respectively by departments, and select `oid` and `cid` with max accept time in each department

```
with cte as (
    select
        oid, cid,
        max(case when status=1 then recorddatetime end) as open,
        max(case when status=2 then recorddatetime end) as accept,
        max(case when status=3 then recorddatetime end) as done
    from 
        mytable
    group by oid, cid
    having 
        max(case when status=1 then recorddatetime end) is not null and max(case when status=2 then recorddatetime end) is not null
        and max(case when status=3 then recorddatetime end) is not null
    order by oid, cid
)
select distinct on(department)
    department, oid, cid,
    ceil(extract(epoch from avg(cte.accept - cte.open) over (partition by department))) as avg_accept_time,
    ceil(extract(epoch from avg(done - open) over (partition by department))) as avg_done_time,
    ceil(extract(epoch from max(accept - open) over (partition by department))) as max_accept_time,
    ceil(extract(epoch from max(done - open) over (partition by department))) as max_done_time,
    ceil(extract(epoch from min(accept - open) over (partition by department))) as min_accept_time,
    ceil(extract(epoch from min(done - open) over (partition by department))) as min_done_time
from cte cte
order by department, max_accept_time desc
```

Second: similar to the first but select all these values for organizations (`oid`)

```
with cte as (
        select
            oid, cid,
            max(case when status=1 then recorddatetime end) as open,
            max(case when status=2 then recorddatetime end) as accept,
            max(case when status=3 then recorddatetime end) as done
        from 
            mytable
        group by oid, cid
        having 
            max(case when status=1 then recorddatetime end) is not null and max(case when status=2 then recorddatetime end) is not null
            and max(case when status=3 then recorddatetime end) is not null
        order by oid, cid
    )
    select distinct on(department, oid)
        department, oid, cid,
        ceil(extract(epoch from avg(cte.accept - cte.open) over (partition by department, oid))) as avg_accept_time,
        ceil(extract(epoch from avg(done - open) over (partition by department, oid))) as avg_done_time,
        ceil(extract(epoch from max(accept - open) over (partition by department, oid))) as max_accept_time,
        ceil(extract(epoch from max(done - open) over (partition by department, oid))) as max_done_time,
        ceil(extract(epoch from min(accept - open) over (partition by department, oid))) as min_accept_time,
        ceil(extract(epoch from min(done - open) over (partition by department, oid))) as min_done_time
    from cte cte
    order by department, oid, max_accept_time desc
```

Comment: what value of `cid` are you expecting when you group by department? minimum, maximum, average?

Comment: what is a `cid`? What's the relationship between it and `department`?

Comment: cid - card id - is foregn key for another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what are you trying to do with your query, but it's really overcomplicated. You first query could be done much simplier with window functions and without joins:

```
with cte as (
    select
        oid, department, cid,
        max(case when status=1 then recordtime end) as open,
        max(case when status=2 then recordtime end) as accept,
        max(case when status=3 then recordtime end) as done
    from mytable
    group by oid, department, cid
)
select
    department, oid,
    extract(epoch from avg(accept - open)) as a_time,
    extract(epoch from avg(done - open)) as d_time,
    extract(epoch from max(accept - open)) as max_a_time,
    extract(epoch from max(done - open)) as max_d_time
from cte
group by department, oid
order by department, oid;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/94015/16)</kbd>**

If you want to get `cid` from which you get max_time, you can use `distinct on` syntax:

```
with cte as (
    select
        oid, department, cid,
        max(case when status=1 then recordtime end) as open,
        max(case when status=2 then recordtime end) as accept,
        max(case when status=3 then recordtime end) as done
    from mytable
    group by oid, department, cid
)
select distinct on (department, oid)
    department, oid, cid,
    extract(epoch from accept - open) as a_time
from cte
order by department, oid, accept - open desc;
```

or use ranking function row_number():

```
with cte as (
    select
        oid, department, cid,
        max(case when status=1 then recordtime end) as open,
        max(case when status=2 then recordtime end) as accept,
        max(case when status=3 then recordtime end) as done
    from mytable
    group by oid, department, cid
), cte2 as (
    select
        department, oid, cid,
        accept, open,
        row_number() over(
              partition by department, oid
              order by accept - open desc
        ) as rn
    from cte
)
select
    department, oid, cid,
    extract(epoch from accept - open) as a_time
from cte2
where rn = 1
order by department, oid
```

<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/94015/24)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your time. your query really easier. i try it on real table later

Comment: that's true. thanks, man! can you tell, is `with cte` expression faster than `join`?